# How do you bleed a column background in Zurb Foundation?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

What is the [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) 4 way of extending the background of a column to the edge of the screen, while maintaining responsiveness?

As an example, see the blue column in the illustration below.

[image]

**Update:**

I was able to achieve this by setting the column's child element to `margin-left: -9999px; padding-left: 9999px;`. But I still wonder if there's a more proper way of doing it.

**Update:**

I was able to come up with a better solution, involving pseudo elements, see below. Thanks @Paulie_D for the tip!

Comment: There is, using a pseudo element but it basically works the same way. http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D, great article, I will try it out using pseudo elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the best option is to use [pseudo elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp). The following CSS code applies bleeding to the left-side column.

```
.column { position: relative; }
.column:before { 
    content: ""; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    right: 100%;
}
```

See [Column Bleeding](http://jsfiddle.net/7yF65/) in action. For more information, see [this article](http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/) (thanks @Paulie_D).

I'd be happy to select a better solution, if anyone has any.